# Cisco ASA 5520 as a home router

Tags: wireless-networking, vlan, dmz, upnp

I have a Cisco ASA 5520 that I recently acquired from work that I am planning to use as my home router.  I also have a Linksys E4200 router and a Linksys WRT610N router, both dual-band, that I would be turning into access points.  I also have a 3rd 5Ghz-only N access point lying around.

I am planning on dividing my home network/home lab into Vlans/subnets like so:

- Vlan 10 - DMZ zone

  - wireless clients, iPads
- Vlan 20 - Servers

  - NAS devices, ESX servers, security systems
- Vlan 100 - Management zone

  - management IPs for Cisco switches, ASA, etc.

My current plan is to have GigabitEthernet0/0 on the ASA connect to my Internet connection and grab an address via DHCP.  All the rest of the ports will connect to a Cisco Catalyst 2960G switch where I will configure all of the VLANs for each port.

My main concern is having things like Vonage (SIP), FaceTime (on iPhones and iPads), and other media-related things such as TiVo/Bluray Player/gaming systems/etc able to open ports as needed via UPnP.  As a result, my first idea was to have all incoming traffic by default sent to a Linksys Router which handles DHCP/UPnP/etc for Vlan 10.  Most devices would connect to that in order to get out to the Internet, while at the same time having to pass traffic through the ASA for access to more "privileged" resources.

Is this possible? Do I need to setup a mixed-context (transparent/routing) environment in order to accomplish this?

Comment: You have a 5520 at home... can.. can.. can I have it? Prettyyy please?

Comment: I have to ask - You want to use a enterprise firewall that can easily net you at least $2k on ebay as a firewall in your home? Why not just sell it and buy new stuff that works great with the services you listed (like an airport extreme), and have $1700 left for beer?

Comment: NAT sucks. Yell at your ISP until they give you IPv6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton and then yell at every service provider in the world to add IPv6 connectivity... you're going to be yelling a lot...

Comment: @MarkHenderson I can use Google and Facebook on IPv6...what more do you need?

Comment: 5520 is on an extended company loan -- no selling it for me. But anyone have any insight on transparent/mixed mode and what it can/can't do? I've only done stuff in routed mode. And I did already upgrade to the latest FW for IPv6 support whenever my ISP has it. :p

Comment: @MichaelHampton - youporn? redtube? stack exchange network ;)

Comment: @Pat still - it makes no sense at using it in your home. An enterprise firewall does not have any knowledge of UPnP (thank god for that), whilst a home firewall should be great with UPnP so you can facetime while you facetube and so on.. Trut me, an ASA in your home is not worth it unless you are going to run a server LAB there.

Comment: @MarkHenderson I have a cluster of two 5520 at home. In case you would like to play with one, you could get WebVPN access via [blackrack.net](http://blackrack.net/).